# Python datetime string 'Wed 10:00 AM UTC+02' to date

Tags: python

I am trying to convert string to datetime string is bit different format "Wed 10:00 AM UTC+02" I tried code below:

Code:

```
date = datetime.strptime('Wed 10:00 AM UTC+02', '%a %X %p %Z%z')
print(date)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Wed 10:00 AM UTC+02' does not match format '%a %X %p %Z%z'
```

From understanding:
%a matches Wed 
%X matches 10:00 
%p matches AM 
%Z%z matches UTC then +02

Comment: Hi novoved828, welcome to SO. Do you understand what the error message says?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know correct format I used https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime but can't find correct formation for date

Comment: I believe the issue might be related to `%z` meaning "UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM" as per official documentation under https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Also time format for `%X` should be `10:00:00` instead.

Answer (score 1):

String needs to be:

```
"Wed 10:00:00 AM UTC+0200"
```

Instead of:

```
"Wed 10:00 AM UTC+02"
```

For `'%a %X %p %Z%z'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming to parse that string you can do as follows:

```
In [14]: from datetime import datetime
In [15]: dateStr = 'Wed 10:00 AM UTC+02'
In [16]: date = datetime.strptime(dateStr + '00', '%a %H:%M %p %Z%z')
In [17]: print(date)
1900-01-01 10:00:00+02:00
```

You may want to include the year as well to the string so as to have an actual date.

The issue within your question is related to `%z` meaning `"UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM"` as per [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). And also the time for `%X` should be `10:00:00` instead as in your original input.